# Using keras api for a multiple output model with the same target value

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

In the case of multi-input or multi-output models according to https://keras.io/models/model/, one can use

```
model = Model(inputs=a1, outputs=[b1, b2])
```

What if b1 and b2 are actually identical target values? I.e. After few initial layers, model has two independent "branches" and each should give the same value. Below is very simplified example

```
a  = Input(shape=(32,))
b1 = Dense(32)(a)
b2 = Dense(32)(a)

model = Model(inputs=a, outputs=[b1,b2])
```

Is there a nicer/better way of doing fit than duplicating target values?

```
model.fit(x_train, [y_train, y_train])
```

Additionaly, if true labels (y_train) are needed during fit (only), one can use them like this

```
model.fit([x_train,y_train], [y_train, y_train])
```

Is there any better solution? Also, what to do with the prediction?

```
model.predict([x_test, y_test_fake_labels])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all for the predict function: model.predict(X) will return a list of numpy arrays in your case. I think you are Kinda confusing tensorflow's session.run() with keras. And for single input and multi output use model.fit(X,[y1,y2]).

I am assuming you are using the tensorflow backend of Keras. In my opinion Keras arguably has the best API  and syntax. It is straightforward and easy to learn compared to tf.learn, slim etc. Even though it runs tensorflow in the background, it is awfully slow compared to running the graph using pure tensorflow. Thus, a small hack which I use sometimes to squeeze performance out of my model is to define the model architecture using keras and then get the pure tensorflow graph from keras using `keras.backend.get_session().graph` and use slim or tf.learn to train
/infer your model. Thus you are using the best of two worlds. Syntactically, this opens up a lot of ways to train/infer your model.

Comment: Okay, so I should use model.fit(X,[y1,y1]) ... This is what I've been using. Just wanted to see if there is an alternative. Will wait to see if anyone has other ideas. If not, will accept you answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Benjamin as far as I know fit, fit_generator, train_on_batch  all have the same syntax. But I have edited my answer to include a small hack which you can use to open up your options

Comment: @AbhijitBalaji can you please add a link or two to the hack you explained above? Thanks.

Comment: @Akash this post is irrelevant now as this was pertaining to TF 1.X and now with TF 2.X Keras is deeply integrated into the TF system that it is blazingly fast and also the dynamic graphs similar to PyTorch. So this hack is obsolete.